# React - can't manage to reset the search result

Tags: reactjs, filter

I believe this is a noob question, but the examples I found about this problem kind of messed up my code I have so far.

In the following function, `value` is the result of what I type in a search bar.

```
this.setState({articles: !this.state.input
    ? false
    : this.state.articles.filter(
        (article) => {
            return article.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.input.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        })
 });
```

This code works fine to filter, but the problem is that when I remove everything from the search bar, it doesn't reset the filter result and I find myself with an empty array and I have to reload the page to have everything back.

I tried to make sure that `this.state.input` wasn't empty, but it didn't work so far

How can I solve this?

**update: I updated my question with how I tried**

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you share the piece of code where you check for input value to not be empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the input value that you are getting is null or undefined. Can you add a condition where in the function it will check if the value is null / undefined or empty string it will just return all the articles.

Also you are storing all the articles in `this.state.article` and then after filtering setting the same state with filtered articles. The next time you filter, it will filter the filtered articles only. So you need to store all the articles somewhere and then have a `filteredArticles` state.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this response, I updated my question ; I think I can move the code to where the articles are `mapped()`  but it seems a bit messy

Comment: Again in the updated code, when the value of input state is undefined, articles state will store a false and wouldn&#39;t show any articles. Its better to have two different states for all articles and filtered articles. I could simply write the code but I want you to try and do it :)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers, I think I found a way to solve this!